# Proving bijectivity of the isomorphism when finding the right adjoint of functor F: Haus $\rightarrow$ to Top

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

Right adjoint of functor F: Haus $\rightarrow$ to Top

Let $X$ be a topological space. We introduce a relation $\sim$ on X by declaring $x \sim y$ if for every continuous map $f : X \rightarrow H$ with $H$ a Hausdorff space we have $f (x) = f (y)$.
∼ is an equivalence relation on $X$ and  the quotient space $X/∼$ is Hausdorff.

There is a functor $h: Top → Haus$ that on objects is given by $h(X) = X/∼$ and on arrows def by:

$f: X \rightarrow Y$ is it the unique continuos map $h(f)$ such that $q_Y\circ F=h(f)\circ q_X$ where $q_Y: Y \rightarrow Y/\sim$ and $q_X: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ are the canonical projections

I have a doubt about my proof that the inclusion functor is right adjoint to h

Proving  that the inclusion: $i: $ Haus $\rightarrow$ Top is the right adjoint of h meansproving that

i) $\text{Hom}_{\text{Top}} (X,i(H)) \xrightarrow{\Phi} \text{Hom}_{\text{Haus}}(h(X),H) $ is an isomorphism .

ii) the naturality of the diagram when fixing one of the variables X or H

I think i can define this isomorphism like this:$f \mapsto \bar f$, where $\bar f$ is the quotiented map given by the universal property of the quotient : $f=\bar f \circ q_X$. It is well-defined because $\bar f$ is unique. But I am having trouble proving that it is bijective. I can't invert the map because $q_X$ (which is the canonical projection) is not injective. How do I prove injectivity and surjectivity?

For injectivity I have that if $\Phi (f)=\Phi(g)$ then $\bar f \circ q_X=\bar g\circ q_X$. But I don't know how to conclude that $\bar f = \bar g$

For surjectivity I need that for every $\bar f $ there is an $f$. but the universal property of the quotient says the contrary that for every $f$ there is an $\bar f$

Comment: Surjectivity is just $f=\bar{f}\circ q_X$.  Injectivity is immediate from checking on elements.

Comment: @user10354138 Another idea I had is that the inverse just maps $\bar f \mapsto f$, and then compose it with the given map on the right and on the left to get the identities, but how come there is an inverse if I can't invert $q_x$ to send it to the other member of the equality ?

Comment: You can invert it.  The point is $X/\sim$ lives inside Top too and all maps $X\to H$ must factor through it, i.e., you have $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Top}}(X,H)\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Top}}(X/\sim, H)$.  Now send that down to $\mathbf{Haus}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Do you mean that $f \circ q_X^{-1}=\bar f \circ q_X \circ q_X^{-1}=\bar f$ is valid? I am not sure about that.  $q_x $is not injective

Comment: It doesn't matter $q_X$ is not injective.  $q_X$ does not feature in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Top}}(X/\sim, H)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition
$$\Phi(f) = \text{ unique map } \bar f : h(x) \to H \text{ such that }  f = \bar f \circ q_X$$
is correct.

$\Phi$ is surjective: Given $g : h(X) \to H$, let $G = g \circ q_X$. By definition $\Phi(G)$ is the **unique map** $\bar G : h(X) \to H$ such that $G = \bar G \circ q_X$. This shows $\Phi(G) = \bar G = g$.

$\Phi$ is injective: Let $f_1, f_2 : X \to H$ such that $\Phi(f_1) =  \Phi(f_2)$. This means $f_1 = \Phi(f_1) \circ q_X = \Phi(f_2) \circ q_X = f_2$.